# SQL - Counting consecutive days with gaps and conditions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a count of consecutive days of sick leave on employees and have gotten some of the way there, but I'm having trouble with a final puzzle.

The code I have seems to work fine if an employee is on sick leave 100%, but fails in cases of partial sick leave.

Anyone have any tips?

The code I have so far:

```
;With CTE
AS
(
SELECT Agent,
    CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date, 104) + ' 00:00:00' ,104) as Date,
    Category,
    (CASE WHEN Category LIKE '%SickLeave%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS SickLeaveFlg,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, (CASE WHEN Category LIKE '%SickLeave%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) ORDER BY CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date, 104) + ' 00:00:00' ,104)) AS DateSeq,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date, 104) + ' 00:00:00' ,104))  AS AgentSeq
FROM Table1
WHERE Agent=’Agent1’ AND Date BETWEEN CONVERT(Datetime, '01.02.2022 00:00:00', 104) AND CONVERT(Datetime, '30.04.2022 23:59:59', 104)
)
SELECT Agent,
    Date,
    Category,
    ResultSeq,
    ResultSeq2
FROM
(
SELECT Agent,
    Date,
    Category,
    (CASE WHEN SickLeaveFlg = 'Y' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, SickLeaveFlg, AgentSeq - DateSeq ORDER BY Date) ELSE 0 END) AS ResultSeq,
    (CASE WHEN SickLeaveFlg = 'Y' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, SickLeaveFlg, DateSeq - Date ORDER BY Date) ELSE 0 END) AS ResultSeq2
FROM CTE
) AS dt
ORDER BY Date
```

ResultSeq seems to produce the right result even with gaps between dates, but seems to me to fail if a date contains both work and sick leave.
ResultSeq2 seems to work even if dates contains both work and sick leave, but not with gaps between dates.

And I can't figure out a way get both solutions in one count.

This is the result I get:
[image: Current results]

And this is what I'm aiming for:

[image: Desired result]

An approximation of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Hours(
Agent VARCHAR(50),
Date DATETIME,
Category VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO Hours (Agent, Date, Category)
VALUES ('Agent1', '25.02.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '26.02.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '27.02.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '02.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '03.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '03.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '03.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '04.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '04.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '06.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '07.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '07.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '07.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '09.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Other absence'),
('Agent1', '10.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Other absence'),
('Agent1', '14.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Other absence'),
('Agent1', '14.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '14.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '15.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '17.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '18.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '19.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '20.03.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '21.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '23.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '23.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '23.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '24.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '24.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '24.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '25.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '25.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '25.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '25.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Other absence'),
('Agent1', '25.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '28.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '28.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '28.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '29.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '29.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '29.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '31.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '31.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '31.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '31.03.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '01.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '01.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '01.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '04.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '04.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '04.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '05.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '05.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '05.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '06.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '06.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '06.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '08.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '09.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '09.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '09.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '10.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '11.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '11.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '11.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Other absence'),
('Agent1', '13.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '13.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '13.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '13.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '14.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '14.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '15.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Holiday'),
('Agent1', '15.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '18.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '18.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '19.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '19.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '19.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '19.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '20.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '20.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '20.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '20.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '21.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '21.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '22.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '22.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '22.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '25.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '25.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '25.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '26.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '26.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '26.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '27.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '27.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '27.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '27.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '29.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '29.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '29.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.04.2022 00:00:00', 'SickLeave'),
('Agent1', '30.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work'),
('Agent1', '30.04.2022 00:00:00', 'Work');
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found a solution with a different approach.
I'll need to tidy up the code some, but at first pass it seems to produce the desired outcome.

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT LOWER(k1.Agent) AS Agent, CAST(k1.Date AS DATE) AS Date, k1.Category
FROM Hours k1
WHERE Category = 'SickLeave'
AND Date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2021 00:00:00', 104))

, CTE2 AS (SELECT LOWER(k2.Agent) AS Agent, CAST(k2.Date AS DATE) AS Date, k2.Category
FROM Hours k2
WHERE Date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2021 00:00:00', 104))

, CTE3 AS (SELECT LOWER(b.Agent) AS Agent, b.Date, (CASE WHEN b.Date = a.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SickLeaveFlg
FROM CTE2 b
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE a ON b.Date = a.Date AND b.Agent = a.Agent)

, CTE4 AS (SELECT LOWER(Agent) AS Agent, Date, SickLeaveFlg
FROM CTE3
GROUP BY Agent, Date, SickLeaveFlg)

, CTE5 AS (SELECT LOWER(Agent) AS Agent, Date, SickLeaveFlg,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, (CASE WHEN SickLeaveFlg LIKE 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) ORDER BY Date) AS DateSeq,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY Date) AS AgentSeq
FROM CTE4)

SELECT  LOWER(Agent) AS Agent,
        Date,
        SickLeaveFlg,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, (CASE WHEN SickLeaveFlg LIKE 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) ORDER BY Date) AS DateSeq,
        (CASE WHEN SickLeaveFlg = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent, SickLeaveFlg, AgentSeq - DateSeq ORDER BY Date) ELSE 0 END) AS ResultSeq
FROM CTE5
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: This query doesn't run on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3774a5ecd6d18eafab094c5343dc02cb

Comment: Replaced "Table" with "Hours" and added space after "," for CTE4.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ab2554dad6b8464bbace66116d5004a

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dateadd` and - `row_number` to group the periods of Sick Leave.
Following your comment I've added a second query to find the total number of days Sick Leave where more than one day taken together ie not counting single days.

> ```
> with distinctHours as(
> select distinct * from Hours),
> cte as(
> select
>   Agent, 
>   Date, 
>   Category,
>   DATEADD(DD,
>   -1 * row_number() over (partition by agent,Category order by date)
>   ,Date)as continuous
> from distinctHours)
> select
>   Agent,
>   min(date) start_date,
>   count(date) number_days,
>   Category
> from cte
> where Category = 'SickLeave'
> group by 
>   Agent,
>   Category,
>   continuous
> order by min(date)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Agent  | start_date              | number_days | Category 
> :----- | :---------------------- | ----------: | :--------
> Agent1 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00.000 |           3 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000 |           1 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-03-15 00:00:00.000 |           1 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-03-17 00:00:00.000 |           4 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-04-13 00:00:00.000 |           3 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-04-18 00:00:00.000 |           5 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-04-25 00:00:00.000 |           3 | SickLeave
> Agent1 | 2022-04-29 00:00:00.000 |           2 | SickLeave
> ```

> ```
> with distinctHours as(
> select distinct * from Hours),
> cte as(
> select
>   Agent, 
>   Date, 
>   Category,
>   DATEADD(DD,
>   -1 * row_number() over (partition by agent,Category order by date)
>   ,Date)as continuous
> from distinctHours),
> preQuery as(
> select
>   Agent,
>   min(date) start_date,
>   count(date) number_days,
>   Category
> from cte
> where Category = 'SickLeave'
> group by 
>   Agent,
>   Category,
>   continuous
> )
> select 
>   Agent,
>   sum(number_days) continuous_sick_leave,
>   Category
> from preQuery
> where number_days > 1
> group by Agent, Category;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Agent  | continuous_sick_leave | Category 
> :----- | --------------------: | :--------
> Agent1 |                    20 | SickLeave
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab64096f07088cda1586e56a34b76095)*

If we want to know the number of days sick leave for Agent1 we can use a much simpler query.

> ```
> select 
>   Agent,
>   count(distinct Date) Days_Sick_Leave
> from Hours 
> where Agent = 'Agent1' and Category = 'SickLeave'
> group by Agent;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Agent  | Days_Sick_Leave
> :----- | --------------:
> Agent1 |              22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ed15a42c71ce10f50bf0718d87b4c6e)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but number of consecutive days in separate periods doesn't get me what I need in the end. I think maybe I found a solution though, by changing my approach a bit.

Comment: I'll admit that I haven't studied your code suggestion in great detail, but the result of "20" isn't correct. The highest number of consecutive days in my data should be 13. And if you add all the periods together the number should be 23.

Comment: I find 22 days for Agent1. If you want to include single days remove the condition `where number_days > 1`. If that is what you want use `select count(distinct Date) from Hours where Agent = 'Agent1' and Category = 'SickLeave' ;`  see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=578baaf58b3e60e377f8c30b1e0e5cba